# Is Keys collection in ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have to remove items from ConcurrentDictionary by some keys. Like this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<SomeClass, string> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<SomeClass, string>();
//adding some values
var keys = dict.Keys.Where(k => k.Name == "Example");
foreach (var key in keys)
    dict.TryRemove(key, out _);
```

The question is: I am enumerating the keys collection when is start looping. What if somebody will change the dict at the same time?
Does dict.Keys returns a snapshot?

Comment: It returns a copy. See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L1931-L1955).

Comment: It returns a `snapshot` (so yes it will work fine). I would suggest using `var keys = dict.Select(z => z.Key).Where(k => k.Name == "Example");` to reduce the need for snapshot (i.e. locking) - i.e. it will generally be faster. Or just `foreach` over the dictionary like in the duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs):

```
public ICollection<TKey> Keys
{
    get { return GetKeys(); }
}

private ReadOnlyCollection<TKey> GetKeys()
{
    int locksAcquired = 0;
    try
    {
        AcquireAllLocks(ref locksAcquired);

        int count = GetCountInternal();
        if (count < 0) throw new OutOfMemoryException();

        List<TKey> keys = new List<TKey>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < _tables._buckets.Length; i++)
        {
            Node current = _tables._buckets[i];
            while (current != null)
            {
                keys.Add(current._key);
                current = current._next;
            }
        }

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<TKey>(keys);
    }
    finally
    {
        ReleaseLocks(0, locksAcquired);
    }
}
```

It locks collection and returns copy of keys

Answer (score 4):

> All public and protected members of ConcurrentDictionary
>   are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.
>   However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the
>   ConcurrentDictionary implements, including extension
>   methods, are not guaranteed to be thread safe and may need to be
>   synchronized by the caller.

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_10